# How to get text with Selenium WebDriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get text using Selenium WebDriver and here is my code. Please note that I don't want to use XPath, because in my case the ID gets changed on every relaunch of the web page.

My code:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("current-stage").getText("my text")
```

HTML:

```html
<span class="current-text" id="yui_3_7_0_4_1389185744113_384">my text</span>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If done interactively, the result may be something like the error message *"AttributeError: 'current-stage' object has no attribute 'getText'"*

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You want just `.text`.

You can then verify it *after* you've got it, don't attempt to pass in what you *expect* it should have.

Comment: Im getting this error - 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: @user3121891, it's `.text`.

Comment: Now Im using this code: 

driver.find_element_by_class_name("current-stage").text("my text")
        
        if text:
            print "pass"
        else:
            print "Fail"

and getting this error -
'unicode' object is not callable

Comment: @user3121891 `driver.find_element_by_class_name("current-stage").text` ....just **text** on it's own. *Nothing* else.

Comment: how to get .text with list of selenium object? I am getting error list object dose not have text method

Comment: You are going to want to loop through the list of selenium objects and apply the `.text` on each item of the for loop.

Comment: My text is getting truncated, showing ellipsis (...) instead of complete the text, any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @GitHunter0 likely dependant on your app - is it truncated on the actual page?

Comment: Yes @Arran, when I inspect the element it shows the complete text but when I try to scrape it, I can only retrieve the abbreviated version which is the one actually displayed in the website (the designers of the site did that because some text can be too long for the intended style)

Comment: When I run this code, it runs without error, but then when I print it I get NULL `abstract = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(text(),'Abstract')]").text`

Comment: The gist may be that [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python/45863411#45863411) it is `getText`, not `text` (perhaps Java was the original *or* most commonly used "driver" language?). In particular, some examples may be in Java. For instance, the default view [on www.selenium.dev](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) is for Java (the others are Python, C#, Ruby, JavaScript, and Kotlin—in that order).

Answer (score 113):

**Python**

```
element.text
```

---

**Java**

```
element.getText()
```

---

**C#**

```
element.Text
```

---

**Ruby**

```
element.text
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this for Python, where are you guys finding this?

Comment: @CharlesSmith if you put a `.` after the element in VSCode, you'll be given a list of suggestions based on what the class accepts. That's how I found this.

Comment: Yes I noticed the same in IntelliJ, was just wondering why it's not in the docs

Comment: @Charles Smith: It is on *[Web element](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/)*, sub section *"Get Element Text"* (at the bottom of the page). There are six different languages and the default is for JavaScript. Click on *"Python"* to see the Python code example.

Comment: (User "Charles Smith" seems to have changed name to "Amon".)

Comment: That link is half-broken by now. An ***example*** for use of `getText` / `text` is now on a sub page to *"Web elements"* —  *[Finding web elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/)*, sub section *"Get element"*. Note also that clicking a tab (e.g., "Python") changes all the views on all pages, not just the one clicked on. That is an example where `getText` / `text` happens to be used. I don't know where the formal documentation for `getText` / `text` is. It must be somewhere on that site.

Comment: What was the point of adding "\*" to "Ruby"? What does it mean?

Answer (score 23):

To print the text *`my text`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *class_name* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "current-stage").get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.current-stage").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='current-stage']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CLASS_NAME* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "current-stage"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.current-stage"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='current-stage']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Very well documented and very detailed. Top answer +1

Answer (score 11):

The answer is:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ctsymbol").text
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name").text
```

This will return the text within the element and will allow you to verify it after that.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct answer. It worked!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\\Python\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tatacliq.com/global-desi-navy-embroidered-kurta/p-mp000000000876745")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(45)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("E:\\Python\\Tatacliq.png")
print ("Executed Successfully")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pdp-promo-title pdp-title']").click()
SpecialPrice = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pdp-promo-title pdp-title']").text
print(SpecialPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

A heads up for anyone finding this thread after the Selenium 4 update.
The driver.find_element_by_*  has been deprecated and using it will give a "deprecationwarning".      The replacement method is: driver.find_element(By.X,"name")   Please look up Selenium 4 info.

Comment: Yes. E.g., from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*. Though it doesn't really answer the question what can be done if the number of elements is different from exactly one (e.g., thrown exceptions if an element is absent. The only solution may be to [catch the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150013) (no way to prevent it)).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this absolutely invaluable when unable to grab something in a custom class or changing id's:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Show Next Date Available')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Show Next Date Available')]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Available')]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Avail')]").text
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* it is absolutely invaluable?

Comment: Why is `.click()` necessary? Why are there three lines with `.text`?

Comment: The question said *"Please note that I don't want to use XPath"*.

Answer (score 0):

to get a text from the element:

```
url=driv.find_element(By.whatDoYouWant, "ClassNameOrwhatDoYouWant").text
print(url)
```

ex:

```
url = web.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a").text
print(url)
```

to get a text from the elements:

ex:

```
for i in range(6):
    var = web.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "input")[i].text
    print(var)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the formatting options available in the editor and mark source code properly, so that your answer is more readable and easier to understand.