# Get value in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have an element:

```
<span class="a-color-price hlb-price a-inline-block a-text-bold">$399.98</span>
```

and I want to extract the price value in dollars which appears in the element’s text.

I have tried:

```
driver.get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search"]/form/div[2]/div/input').get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: That span does not have a `value` attribute. So you'd be interested in getting the HTML of the span

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Comment: driver.get_element_by_css_selector('#nav-search form span.hlb-price').text

Comment: @Andersson - nope it is other issue

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SpanVariable = driver.get_element_by_xpath('Put Xpath Here')

SpanVariableValue = SpanVariable.text
print SpanVariableValue  # $399.98
```

You need to grab the text of the element you are looking at. Place the element you located in a variable, and then you can call selenium functions to it. In this case, `.text` grabs the text of your span element for you.

Comment: What Xpath are you using

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, it should be pretty simple. I use C# but based on what you've given I'd try this. And if this doesn't work, use a upper case 't' for the ending '.Text;' part of the call.

```
my_spanText = driver.get_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-color-price hlb-price a-inline-block a-text-bold']").text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hlb-subcart"]/div[1]/span/span[2]').text