# How to get the value of an element in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I have got this HTML element in my Python (3.6.3) code (as a Selenium *webelement* of course):

```
<span class="ocenaCzastkowa masterTooltip" style="color:#000000;" alt="Kod:
pd1<br/>Opis: praca domowa<br/>Waga: 2,00<br/>Data: 12.09.2017<br/>Nauczyciel:
(NAME CENSORED)">5</span>
```

And I want to get the value at the end (which is 5 in this case) and I have got no idea how to get it.

Obviously, I can't use `webelement.get_attribute()` because I don't know the name of the attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Comment: [Two nearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python/65863434#65863434) ***identical answers*** [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139676/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-element-in-python-selenium/65861880#65861880) it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the following code:

```python
span_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ocenaCzastkowa.masterTooltip")
span_element.text # This will return "5".
```

PS: You can also use `span_element.get_attribute("value")`.

Comment: I am confused. Before, i used find_elements_by_xpath(many elements, and this worked, all the webelements were there) elementlist[x].getattribute('value') did not work. Although now, when i used find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector).get_attribute('value') it returns the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: The error :`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.` I tried doing some research on this error but did not get far.

Comment: @Koteu, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Comment: @Ratmir Yeah i know, i'll wait a while, perhaps somebody figures out the problem. If there will be no suggestions i will accept your anwser. By the way, Thank You for the instant anwser.

Comment: @Koteu, `.text` also must work. Maybe, needed to wait (implicit or explicit). You didn't push your code.

Comment: Somehow or other, now trying it again in idle, again creating the list in the very same way as before, the error does not appear anymore (when refering to the element from the list). Thank You. Still, any clarification on the error wich appeared would be appreciated

Comment: I'm doing this in Feb 2019, using Python 3.7 and latest selenium: with `<a></a>` tag element, `element.get_attribute("value")` returns `None`, but `element.text` does return the text inside `<a>` tag....

Comment: @WillCroxford, it depends on the realization of your site. Maybe, you need to use there explicit wait before interacting with the element.

Answer (score 2):

To print the textContent, i.e. **5**, you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```python
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ocenaCzastkowa.masterTooltip").text)
  ```
- Using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

  ```python
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ocenaCzastkowa masterTooltip']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```python
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ocenaCzastkowa.masterTooltip"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```python
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ocenaCzastkowa masterTooltip']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```python
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

You can find a relevant discussion in *[How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)*