# How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to Python and Web Scraping so please bear with me. I have been trying to build a web scraping tool to open a web page, log-in, and retrieve a certain value. Thus far, I have been able to open the web page and log-in. However, I simply cannot find a way to retrieve (print) the value that I require. This is what my current code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')

url = "xxxxxxxx"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("xxxxx")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("xxxxx")
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form#frmMain > a:nth-child(4)")
elem.click()

html = '''<p class="value noWrap" data-bind="text: MarketValue">R 4 516 469.32</p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.string)

driver.quit()
```

The value I require is embedded in the html variable above "R 4 516 469.32". However, this value changes on a daily basis. I have tried using xpath and css, but the value in question seems to be hidden for some odd reason. How can I refer to the element dynamically in order to be able to retrieve the new value every day?

Please note: I have blanked out the url as this is a website used for company purposes.

Please help!

Thanks so much

Comment: What do you mean by "the value in question seems to be hidden"?

Comment: @JackFleeting if i print out the page this is how the html appears for the above: <p class="value noWrap" data-bind="text: MarketValue"></p>

Comment: I just copied and pasted the main 4 lines of your code (beginning with `html = `) and ended up with `R 4 516 469.32`. So I can't see what the problem is. Same thing if I change the last line to `print(p.text)`.

Comment: I may have not been clear, the HTML code in my code above specifies the market value. However I was looking for a dynamic solution to the above paste code as the market value changes everyday and I would not like to retrieve the HTML string every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to extract the text within the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.value.noWrap[data-bind$='MarketValue']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='value noWrap' and contains(@data-bind,'MarketValue')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```