# Check if text exists on a page, but read the text from a variable (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web, text, find

I am trying to find a matching text on a page with Selenium, but I am not sure how to make it read an input string from a variable.
For example:

```
video_title = 'Michael Jackson - Thriller'
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), video_title)]")
```

The code above does not give me good results, as it probably searches literary for "video_title", and not the string inside.
I omited the standard quotes arround video_title in the code above, in hopes of Selenium looking at it as a variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible to do? With Selenium, or some other way?
Thanks!

Comment: Might be similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139676/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-element-in-python-selenium/48139708

Comment: If you won't know if it possible to run this code and you will see the result

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that I am expetimetning with the code, but it does not work I want it to. It searches for "video_title" literary, and not the string inside.

Comment: Search for "python string formatting" for examples of how to construct a string value from a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the video title as a variable instead of as text, as displayed in the code below:

```
video_title = 'Michael Jackson - Thriller'
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + video_title + "')]")
```

Note the extra single quote around `video_title`, required because it's a string. At runtime this will result in the following XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Michael Jackson - Thriller')]
```