# Trying to get Get text out of div class using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

HTML  div class that contains the data I wish to print

[image]

```
<div class="gs_a">LR Binford&nbsp;- American antiquity, 1980 - cambridge.org </div>
```

This is my code so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver

def Author (SearchVar):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/tutau/Downloads/chromedriver")

    driver.get ("https://scholar.google.com/")

    SearchBox = driver.find_element_by_id ("gs_hdr_tsi")

    SearchBox.send_keys(SearchVar)

    SearchBox.submit()

    At = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector ('#gs_res_ccl_mid > div:nth-child(1) > div.gs_ri > div.gs_a')

    print (At)

Author("dog")
```

All that comes out when I print is

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
>   (session="9aa956e2bd51f510dd626f6937b01c0e",
>   element="0.6506218589189958-1")

not the text 
I am new to selenium Help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Comment: Can you please paste the HTML. The screenshot is not so helpful.

Comment: You should use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`, rather than `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector`.  And should be `print (At.text)`

Comment: you are printing the element with print(At),use `print(At.text)` instead, not related but i suggest using requests with Beautifulsoup instead of selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were almost there. Perhaps, as per the *HTML* and your *code trials* you have shared, you are seeing the desired output.

### Explaination

Once the following line of code gets executed:

```
At = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector ('#gs_res_ccl_mid > div:nth-child(1) > div.gs_ri > div.gs_a')
```

*WebElement* **At** refers to the desired element(single element in your list). In your next step, as you invoked `print (At)` the *WebElement* **At** is printed which is as follows:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9aa956e2bd51f510dd626f6937b01c0e", element="0.6506218589189958-1")
```

### Solution

Now, as per your question, if you want to extract the text **LR Binford - American antiquity, 1980 - cambridge.org**, you have to invoke either of the methods through the element:

- [**`text`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text): Gets the text of the element.
- [**`get_attribute(attributeName)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute): Gets the given attribute or property of the element.

So you need to change the line of code from:

```
print (At)
```

To either of the following:

- Using **`text`**:

  ```
  print(At.text)
  ```
- Using **`get_attribute(attributeName)`**:

  ```
  print(At.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Your own code with minor adjustments:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver

  def Author (SearchVar):

      options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
      options.add_argument("start-maximized")
      options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
      driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
      driver.get ("https://scholar.google.com/")
      SearchBox = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
      SearchBox.send_keys(SearchVar)
      SearchBox.submit()
      At = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector ('#gs_res_ccl_mid > div:nth-child(1) > div.gs_ri > div.gs_a')
      for item in At:
          print(item.text)

  Author("dog")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  …, RJ Marles, LS Pellicore, GI Giancaspro, TL Dog - Drug Safety, 2008 - Springer
  ```

Comment: Well there's an indentation error in the for loop (at the print) and you don't need the 'div' in the CSS selector. Again: this will throw an error in case there is Unicode in the element of interest

Comment: I only see this because YOU (among others) helped me with your contributions on SO in the past

Comment: Thanks @sudonym Keep an eye over my answers time to time. Your feedback and support always brings the best out of me. Not sure why the indentation doesn't gets pasted as it should. However corrected it and added cushion for _Unicode_ as well. But I am not in favour of any change to _OP's approach_ until and unless it is absolutely necessary. Essentially that kills OP's innovation. Hence `css_selector` I left untouched.

Comment: Get it - I'll keep monitoring your contributions trust on that

Comment: cheers bro much appreciated, this code will jot work in atom however had to switch to visual studios. throws a unicode error.

Answer (score 1):

**Intro**

First, I recommend to css-select your target on selenium's `page_source` using a faster parser.

```
import lxml
import lxml.html

# put this below SearchBox.submit()

CSS_SELECTOR = '#gs_res_ccl_mid > :nth-child(1) > .gs_ri > .gs_a' # Define css
source = driver.page_source                                       # Get all html
At_raw = lxml.html.document_fromstring(source)                    # Convert
At = At_raw.cssselect(CSS_SELECTOR)                               # Select by CSS
```

**Solution 1**

Then, you need to extract the `text_content()` from your web element and encode it properly.

```
At = At.text_content().encode('utf-8') # Get text and encode
print At
```

**Solution 2**

In case `At` contains more than one line and unicode, you can also remove those:

```
At = [l.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','') for line in At \                 # replace unicode
         for l in line.text_content().strip().encode('utf-8').splitlines() \ # Get text
               if l.strip()]                # only consider if line contains characters
print At
```

Comment: OP explicitly said that wants to get output ***using selenium in python*** while you suggests to use `lxml` which looks much more complicated than simply add the `text` property...

Comment: my proposed solution requires python and selenium. (driver.page_source) . In fact, that is the first sentence of my answer. I suggest to use a different PARSER for performance reasons and I also suggest to use a way of text extraction that works in all scenarios, not just in some.

Comment: If `text`doesn't work, OP might use `get_attribute("textContent")`.  Also using third-party library to extract one text value doesn't seem to bring much efficiency or improvements

Comment: I agree with you. As soon as OP decides to scrape more than one value in the future, my code might help more. I benchmarked this and in essence doubled my throughput/s using sel's page_source + lxml compared to vanilla selenium. In the meanwhile, let's hope his value does not contain any currency symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the element. Print (**At.text**) instead of **At**.

Comment: AFAIK this won't work if you are dealing with unicode (currency symbols etc.). Also, this won't remove whitespace-only lines and similar artefacts