# How can I extract text within html tags using Python's selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a method in Python's selenium module that will allow me to extract the text within html  tags. Below is the html I'm working with:

```
<span class="user-bot-score">Text I want</span>
```

I'm able to select the span tag in Python with the following line:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("user-bot-score")
```

I'm wondering if there's a selenium method I can use to extract the text from within the span element?

Comment: Try `element.text` or `element.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: element.text worked :) Thank you

Comment: @Alan I didn't post it because there's a number of questions already asking the same thing. It seemed too close to a duplicate and too simple an answer. It looks like OP has posted it in his own answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("user-bot-score").text
```