# Selenium Chrome Driver 74.0.3729.6 Issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written some code to click a link to download the course slides via our university course website.
My code is bellow:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
    if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
    return driver.execute_script("""
        var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
        if (items.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
            return items.map(e => e.file_url);
        """)

try:
    print("6. Detail Resource.\n")
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    url = "http://course.ucas.ac.cn/access/content/group/155852/1.%E8%AF%BE%E4%BB%B6/CourseInfo.pptx"
    file = browser.find_element_by_xpath((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="'+url+'"]'))
    file.click()
    # waits for all the files to be completed and returns the paths
    paths = WebDriverWait(browser, 120, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
    print(paths)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The HTML code of the link I wanna click is here:

```
<a href="http://course.ucas.ac.cn/access/content/group/155852/1.%E8%AF%BE%E4%BB%B6/CourseInfo.pptx" target="_self"><img src="/library/image/sakai/ppt.gif?panel=Main" border="0" alt="PowerPoint " hspace="0">
```

I run my code, but it shows the error.

```
Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
(Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6(255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.4 x86_64)
```

I have searched the chromedriver official website, but no found chrome driver for 74.0.3729.131. Could somebody help me fix the bug?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is here.

```
file = browser.find_element_by_xpath((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="' + url + '"]'))
```

You have used `find_element_by_xpath` it takes string value of the locator.That is why the error you are getting.

```
Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
(Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6(255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.4 x86_64)
```

Change above code to.

```
file = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to "click" the downloaded document by means of Selenium functions as Chrome Downloads are under [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) to wit they're exposed as [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

[image]

Looking [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?q=shadow%20dom&unscoped_q=shadow%20dom) and [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Mobile+Web+Testing+On+Chrome+With+Android) reading the inner HTML of the Shadow DOM is possible via [getText() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python), however you will not be able to interact with the elements normally.

Assuming all above I would recommend simply [downloading the necessary file(s) by Python means](https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/) and [executing the associated application(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python) or whatever you were going to do with the downloaded file(s)