# How to get the some text value in this html with Selenium Webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get the text value "This Text 1" and "This Text 2" with selemiun and python from the following html code:

```
<p>
   <b>Studio:</b>
   <a href="http://www.somelink.com/some_page/">This Text 1</a>
   " | "
   <b>Director:</b> This Text 2
</p>
```

I have tried in several ways like with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Director:')]")
```

but without get the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text `This Text 1` and `This Text 2`
Use following options.

To get `This Text 1` Use following `xpath`

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p/b[contains(.,'Studio')]/following::a").text)
```

---

Use `JavaScript Executor` to fetch `This Text 2`

```
element=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(.,'Director')]"))
print(element.strip())
```