# How get textContent by Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I would like to get emails from `https://spamwc.de/` using `Selenium (Python)`.

In html DOM it looks like: `document.getElementById("mails").textContent` 
(it works, when no emails in mailbox it gives "...no mails...", and it's fine)

I would like to get the same result using Selenium.

My code:

```
        try:
            mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").getAttribute("outerHTML")
            print("mails:", mails)
        except:
            print("mails: no outerHTML")

        try:
            mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").getAttribute("innerHTML")
            print("mails:", mails)
        except:
            print("mails: no innerHTML")

        try:
            mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").getAttribute("textContent")
            print("mails:", mails)
        except:
            print("mails: no textContent")
```

Result (exceptions: `'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'`):

```
mails: no outerHTML
mails: no innerHTML
mails: no textContent
```

Of course the element with `id="mails"` exists.

Example when mailbox (e.g.  test@akkecuwa.ga) is empty:
`document.getElementById('mails').textContent`

Result:
`There are no mails for you, sorry.`

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I cant see document.getElementById("mails").textContent in the above link https://spamwc.de/. Can you please send some other reference?

Comment: Sorry. After you go to  spamwc.de you must fill name of email and press "Send". Then you will be redicted to mailbox with mails.

Comment: You can get by xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="mails"]/span").text`

Comment: I am not familiar with xpath. Exception: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='mails'/span]"}

Comment: try logging entire html before the `driver.find` line like this `browser.get(yourUrl)
html_source = browser.page_source` And see if it has the element you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Comment: Shweta Valunj, your code works. I added 3s of sleep after press "Send" button. I think the problem was the content wan't loaded yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The method you want to call is get_attribute(), not getAttribute(). It should work fine after that.

```
    try:
        mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").get_attribute("outerHTML")
        print("mails:", mails)
    except:
        print("mails: no outerHTML")

    try:
        mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print("mails:", mails)
    except:
        print("mails: no innerHTML")

    try:
        mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").get_attribute("textContent")
        print("mails:", mails)
    except:
        print("mails: no textContent")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that You're probably willing to get the Text out of these emails.

```
mails = self.driver.find_element_by_id("mails").get_attribute("outerHTML")
content = mails.text //just search for the correct method to get this text
```

There are probably more than one mails that You'd like to check, so instead of this find_element_by_id try find_elements_by_id (which will find all elements that fits your selector) then You can loop through list of these elements, and get their content for each of this elements included in the list.

Comment: is this relevant to python?

Comment: Good catch, I've removed the unnecessary "var" from this variable and the semicolons

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. 
Yes, I  want to get the text of these emails. 
In HTML (document.getElementById("mails").textContent) all emails are presented together. No loop is required. Mails are not presented in HTML page source. Your code caused exception 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'.

Comment: That's because it should be get_attribute instead of this getAttribute, I've updated the answer