# Extracting text from element after using driver.find_elements_by_id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to extract the data in a table, which I have located doing the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S11_CC_Contenders_EU")

player = driver.find_elements_by_id("row0")
print(player)
```

From player I get

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a15cc6e3b18c893aa11262b3daa87786", element="1aef44eb-dec2-415b-a3da-7187a143387e")>]
```

And now I would like to retrieve the data that is in the table. How do I do that?

EDIT: I should have said, that when I do

```
text = player.text[0]
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Comment: No. When I do .text I get AttributeError: "list" object has no attribute "text"

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and look over it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I am an idiot. I did player.text[0] instead of player[0].text. Code that works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S11_CC_Contenders_EU")

player = driver.find_elements_by_id("row0")
text = player[0].text
print(text)
```