# How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to get only " text ... " not using .split() or index slicing

HTML:

```
<a class="call_recipe" href="/recipes/2913">
      " text ... "
      <strong> something~ </strong>
    </a>
```

HTML Snapshot:

[image: ![]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print *text ...* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, *childNodes* and `strip()`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.call_recipe[href^='/recipes']")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH`, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='call_recipe' and starts-with(@href, '/recipes')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to get specific text that belongs to div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945364/how-to-get-specific-text-that-belongs-to-div-class/65945658#65945658)
- [How to get text from textnodes seperated by whitespace using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151864/how-to-get-text-from-textnodes-seperated-by-whitespace-using-selenium-and-python/63155068#63155068)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("call_recipe").text
```

I think this is what you're after.

[How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the

```py
 "find_element_by_class_name("some_text").getText()"
```

or to better match the text you can use

```
"driver.find_element_by_xpath("..").text"
```

Hope this is helpful