# How to get text from textnodes seperated by whitespace using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am on this page:

https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics

When you click on any "i" icon next to a player, a popup window appears. Then, i want to get the surname of the player. This is how "inspect element" looks like ("whitespace" actually appears within a box):

```
<h2 class="ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2 ijAScJ">
 Kevin
 whitespace
 De Bruyne
```

What i want to do is to take the text that appears after the whitespace. I can get the full text (ie both name and surname) using this:

```
player_full_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2 ijAScJ"]').text
```

but how can i get the surname only (ie what appears after the whitespace)? Note that for other players it could have been like this:

```
<h2 class="ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2 ijAScJ">
 Gabriel Fernando
 whitespace
 de Jesus
```

or like this:

```
<h2 class="ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2 ijAScJ">
 Dean
 whitespace
 Henderson
```

ie splitting the text and taking the last one or two elements will not work.

Comment: Add your code trials to reproduce the case.

Comment: .split on the whitespace chars - '\n' or whatever? Element [-1] should be the surname.

Comment: Why don't you use the following XPath on the same page to get the player names ? `//div[starts-with(@class,"ElementInTable__Name")]` ? Because of players like `Gabriel Fernando de Jesus` where the `de` is missing ?

Comment: Many thanks to all - @E.Wiest: yes, this is a solution, but i still wanted to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surname of the player is the second or last text node within it's parent [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). So extract the surname e.g. **De Bruyne** from *Kevin De Bruyne* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, *childNodes* and `strip()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody/tr/td/button"))).click()
  print( driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2")))).strip())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  De Bruyne
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, *childNodes* and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody/tr/td/button"))).click()
  print( driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.ElementDialog__ElementHeading-gmefnd-2")))).splitlines())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['De Bruyne']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)