# Get text from text node above span tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Below is some of the html I'm trying to scrape using python and selenium.

```
<h2 class ="page-title">  
    Strange Video Titles
    <span class="duration">28 min</span>  
    <span class="video-hd-mark">720p</span> 
</h2>
```

Below is my code:

```
title=driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-title').text
print(title)
```

However, when I run this, it prints everything within the h2 tag, including the text in the span classes. I've tried to adding [0] or [1] at the end to specify I only want the first line of text but that doesn't work. How can I only print the video title, which is located above the span classes?

**Edit - I think this is the solution**

So I've decided to do the following:

```
title=driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-title').text
duration = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/h2/span[1]').text  
vid_quality =driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/h2/span[2]').text 


if (duration) in title:
    title = title.replace(duration, "")
if(vid_quality) in title:
    title = title.replace(vid_quality,"")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print only the video title i.e. **Strange Video Titles** as it is a *Text Node* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='page-title']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, *childNodes* and `strip()`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.page-title")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to get text from textnodes seperated by whitespace using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151864/how-to-get-text-from-textnodes-seperated-by-whitespace-using-selenium-and-python/63155068#63155068)
- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.contents`

```
spam = """
<h2 class ="page-title">  
    Strange Video Titles
    <span class="duration">28 min</span>  
    <span class="video-hd-mark">720p</span> 
</h2>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')
h2 = soup.find('h2')
print(h2.contents[0].strip())

# ALTERNATIVE -  remove the span tags
for span in h2.find_all('span'):
   span.decompose()
print(h2.text.strip())
```

output

```
Strange Video Titles
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to help. I'm using selenium, not bs4, so your solution wouldn't work. However, if you see the edit I made to my question, I changed how to find the span text. However, I'm still having a bit of difficulty. If it's not too much to ask, could you please take a look at the edit I made? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `selenium` part

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located()`

Use `JS executor` and use the `firstChild` to get the title value

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2.page-title")))
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', element))
```

You need to import below library

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```