# How to get specific text that belongs to div class

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, textnode

```html
<div class="col_5"> 
       <br>
            <i class="phone">
                  :: Before
                  </i>
                  0212 / 897645
            <br>
                  
                  <i class="print">
                  :: Before
                  </i>
                  0212 / 111111
            <br>
       <br>
</div>
```

Firstly I am gettin datas from a website and applying these datas to excel by using pandas.

I have a html code as stated above. I want to take the phone number which is come after the `<i class='phone'>` and pass the other one. However the phone number doesnot belongs to I class so I could only get the numbers by getting 'xpath' of the `<div class='col_5'>` but this is not safe for me because some 'divs' do not has the phone number and has only print number and this could be deadly for me. For example I try to find the xpath of `<div class='col_5'>` like that

```
num = browser.find_element_by_xpath('div[1]/div/div[103]/div[2]')
num.text.split('\n')
```

and the output is

```
['02243 / 80343', '02243 / 83261']
```

```html
<div class="col_5"> 
       <br>
            <i class="phone">
                  ::Before
                  </i>
                  
               <br>
                  <i class="print">
                  ::Before
                  </i> 
                  0201 / 623424
               <br>
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:info@someone.com"> <i class="envelope"> </i> E-Mail</a>
 </div>
```

Above
I shared the code which does not have the phone number but has the print number only. When I get the xpath of `<div class='col_5'>` in the second code I get the print number only and while these happens I add my data print number as phone number. And this is causing incorrect data. And when I do the same exact things as stated above the output is

```
['0201 / 623424', '', 'E-Mail']
```

So when I try to take the first item, it takes the print number. If there is phone number, I just want to take it, if not, take it and move on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text *`0212 / 897645`* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, *childNodes* and `strip()`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.col_5")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH`, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[1]/div/div[103]/div[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[4])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)
- [How to get text from textnodes seperated by whitespace using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151864/how-to-get-text-from-textnodes-seperated-by-whitespace-using-selenium-and-python/63155068#63155068)