# Selenium / XPath Getting HTML between two tags

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

How to extract

- message names (e.g. `Message 1`),
- received timestamp (e.g. `Received: 214-2342-234`),
- **and most difficult: message text** (e.g. `This is message nr. 1 it contains...`)

of this HTML using Selenium 4 (preferably XPath)?
I am using Python.

```html
<body>
  <p class="pclass">
    <a name="msg1"></a>
    Message 1:
    <a href="..."> Link1</a>
    <span> Received: 214-2342-234</span>
  </p>
  <br>This is message nr. 1 it contains different stuff like <b>bold text</b>, etc.<br><br>

  <p class="pclass">
    <a name="msg2"></a>
    Message 2:
    <a href="..."> Link1</a>
    <span> Received: 214-46546-23532</span>
  </p>
  <br>Message nr. 2 may contain other stuff (maybe even a table...)<br><br>

  <p class="pclass">
    <a name="msg3"></a>
    Message 3:
    <a href="..."> Link1</a>
    <a href="..."> Link2</a>
    <span> Received: 214-7876967666</span>
  </p>
  <br>This message contained 2 hyperlinks before the received-timestamp.<br><br>

  <a href="close.php">Close Messages</a>
</body>
```

Querying data within nodes is pretty easy but how about this text somewhere between tags?
What I currently have is getting the 'msg1', 'msg2', ...:

```
msgs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@name, 'msg')]")
print(msgs[0].get_attribute('name')) # prints 'msg1'
```

Comment: are you sure the html is correct as per the given html  This is message nr. 1 it contains different stuff like is inside bodt tag

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML Yes,You can achieve that using string manipulation and other approach like `Splitlines()` and js executor.

Identify the `p` tag and then find `childNodes` value, and then `span` text.

For breaking line you need to identify `body tag` and then use  `Splitlines()`

Code:

```
i=2
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.pclass'):
    print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', item).strip())
    print(item.find_element_by_xpath("./span").text)
    message=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text.splitlines()
    print(message[i])
    i=i+4
    print("#########################################")
```

**Console Output:**

```
Message 1:
Received: 214-2342-234
This is message nr. 1 it contains different stuff like bold text, etc.
#########################################
Message 2:
Received: 214-46546-23532
Message nr. 2 may contain other stuff (maybe even a table...)
#########################################
Message 3:
Received: 214-7876967666
This message contained 2 hyperlinks before the received-timestamp.
#########################################
```

Answer (score 0):

1. message names

   `text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p[2]').get_attribute('innerText') name = text.split(':')[0] print(name)`
2. received timestamp

   `timestamp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p[1]/span').get_attribute('innerText')     print(timestamp)`
3. message text

   `import re`

   `message_text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerText')`
   `print(re.findall(re.escape('\n\n\n')+"(.*)"+re.escape('\n\n\n\n'),message_text)[0])`

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *texts* from the *text nodes* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()`can use the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  - To extract *Message 1:* :

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/p[@class='pclass']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
    ```
  - To extract *Received: 214-2342-234* :

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/p[@class='pclass']//span"))).text)
    ```
  - To extract *This is message nr. 1 it contains...* :

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[7])
    ```
- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  - To extract *Message 1:* :

    ```
    print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/p[@class='pclass']")))).strip())
    ```
  - To extract *Received: 214-2342-234* :

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/p[@class='pclass']//span"))).text)
    ```
  - To extract *This is message nr. 1 it contains...* :

    ```
    print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "body")))).strip())
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)