# Get the value of in html span selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

A certain span icon on binary.com has the following html code:

```
<span id="spot" style="" data-value="3862.76" class="price_moved_down">3,862.76</span>
```

where the data value changes every 2 second. I want to use that that data value on my web automation script yet I do not know where to start please help. refer to the picture to understand.

[image]

Comment: Selenium is automated, but creates a new browser window. For just getting this value, requests or beautiful soup may be better suited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text **3,862.76** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.price_moved_down#spot[data-value]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='price_moved_down' and @id='spot'][@data-value]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text **3,862.76** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.price_moved_down#spot[data-value]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price_moved_down' and @id='spot'][@data-value]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 1):

The number is the text value of the element. So once you find the element using selenium

```
my_span = driver.find_element_by.....
```

You can just called the text attribute on the element

```
print(my_span.text)
```