# Get the text contained in all the tag having the attribute specify as "<div class='wld' text >" with the WebDriver Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to recieve the "text" contained in all the `<div class='wld' text >`.
I tried this code :

```
match_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld").text
 
print(match_results)
```

and this

```
  match_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld")
     
    print(match_results.text)
```

and as well try the methods answered this question [How to get text with selenium web driver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python)
that resemble the method that I did more high.

I get this error message :

```
 match_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld").text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

and this

```
print(match_results.text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

When I Remove `.text` here is what this

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="409c9b33d38ef268b14fe6f18992b61c", element="2321a252-8cb9-4fd1-8f8a-af837c28b35c")>,
```

and this for each element "text" contained in `<div class='wld' text >`
What can I do for display all the "text", method to used ?
I'm heard that it would have to through BeautifulSoup in others forum, your notice ?

Important information that I forgeted of precis : it is that I arrive to access the first element of way individual with method  `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld").text` for exemple and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'find_elements' method will return a list of elements and it does not have 'text' attribute.

So if you want to get list of elements try this.

```
match_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld")
for elem in match_results:
   print(elem.text)
```

Or if you want to get only one element try this.

```
match_results = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld").text
```