# How can I store an XPath as a variable in Python Selenium?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I want to be able to select text on a website, store it, and then turn that stored information into a variable. More specifically as seen in the picutre below, my goal is for the selected name, in this case, John J. John, somehow be copied, turned into a variable, and then printed, all without emulating any key binds.

> [HTML Inspect element photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlV83.jpg)

The code I have tried to use to get the information is this:

```
selectedName = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign_in_box"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').get_attribute("div")

print (selectedName)
```

The return I am getting is this:

```
None
```

I know that the problem almost definetly lies somewhere in the path, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: There is no element with the ID `#sign_in_box` in the HTML output. Please make sure, that you provide a full but minimal example to your problem, so that others have a chance to spot errors or mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your xpath is correct, you should put `.text` instead of `.get_attribute("div")` since it will not return the text you want, but the div itself.

[How to get text with Selenium WebDriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Try

```
selectedName = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign_in_box"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
```