# How to get text with Selenium WebDriver in a For Loop Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to run a for loop in a [website](https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/31/Tournaments/95/Seasons/7243/Stages/15996/TeamStatistics/Brazil-Brasileir%C3%A3o-2018) table with Selenium. I'm using Xpath to get the data.

When I run this solo, I get the proper output:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-team-stats-summary-content"]/tr[1]/td[2]').text
```

But when I put in a for loop to extract all values, it runs an error

```
vals = (list(np.arange(0,20,1)))
for i in vals :
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-team-stats-summary-content"]/tr[i]/td[2]').text)
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
 {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="top-team-stats-summary-content"]/tr[i]/td[2]"}
```

This is the HTML

```
<td class="goal   ">59</td>
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Before coming to a post, I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python) post, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `i` parameter into the `xpath` expression.

```
xpath = '//*[@id="top-team-stats-summary-content"]/tr[{}]/td[2]'.format(i)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text)
```

or simply concatenate the `i` value as suggested by groeterud

Comment: Thank you! It just solved my problem. It was a silly one, how could I miss that. I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close mate. You simply need to concatonate your variable i within the string.

```
vals = (list(np.arange(0,20,1)))
for i in vals :
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-team-stats-summary-content"]/tr['+i+']/td[2]').text)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! 

unfortunetly I got this error: 
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int32") to str`

Comment: right.. you have to convert it to a string within the forloop. Anyway, saw that the above answer worked for you, so that's great :)