# Printing Text from Element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I want to print this part to the console. (marked) [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp66W.png)

This is my last try:

I get this error with my last try:

Unable to locate element:

> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a/span"}

Keep in my this text changes.

```
followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a/span').GetAttribute("innerHTML")

print("Followers: " + followers)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And if you have one, does this answer it? [How to get text with Selenium WebDriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: The text changes, and when i try to locate it using XPath it cant find it.

Comment: @ZetlexDK Can you share the related HTML source ? or the URL

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/travel.themepage/

Comment: Inspect the followers text thing. :)

Comment: @YaDavMaNish ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below xpath :

```
//a[contains(@href, 'followers')]/span
```

and there isn't any `GetAttribute` method available in Selenium - Python binding.

Instead you can use :

```
followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'followers')]/span").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print("Followers: ", followers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this

```
followerTxt=driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//a[@class='-nal3 ']/span)[2])")

print("Total followers: ",followerTxt.text)
```

I've check based on the element index

[image]

This is my Output

Comment: Hey this worked, but wrong one. I got how many im following and not how many followers i have.

Comment: @Zetlex DK Can you check my updated answer, I include the snap of the output which shows follower not how many you follow