# Using selenium in Python, select HTML page element content with xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

In the Xpath Helper plugin, I was able to get the HTML tag content:

```
QUERY：//div[@id="cardModel"]/div[@class="modal-dialog"]/div[@class="modal-content"]//tr[1]/td[1]//tr/td[2]/div/span/text()

RESULTS (1)：Enrico
```

The result is:

```
Enrico
```

But in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import etree

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
detailUrl = 'https://www.enf.com.cn/3d-energy-1?directory=panel&utm_source=ENF&utm_medium=perc&utm_content=22196&utm_campaign=profiles_panel'
driver.get(detailUrl)
html_ele_detail = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(5)

companyPhone = html_ele_detail.xpath('//div[@id="cardModel"]/div[@class="modal-dialog"]/div[@class="modal-content"]//tr[1]/td[1]//tr/td[2]/div/span/text()')
print("companyPhone = ", companyPhone)
```

companyPhone shows empty, what's wrong?Thank you all for solving this problem

Comment: `//div[@id="cardModel"]/div[@class="modal-dialog"]/div[@class="modal-content"]//tr[1]/td[1]//tr/td[2]/div/span/text()` this does not represent anything in HTMLDOM, Which element you are trying to interact with?

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using the **selenium** library, you do not need to use **etree** library.

For this application **selenium** library is enough

see the example below and adapt for your purpose:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
detailUrl = 'your url here'
driver.get(detailUrl)

web_element_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath directory here').text

print(web_element_text)
```

See some other examples in another topic by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Let me know if this was helpful.