# How do I get text that appear on page from div?

Tags: python, selenium

The page source look like this:

```
    <div class="caption">
                        <div id="question_speaker" style="display: none;"><img 
    src="../server/static/loudspeaker.png"></div>
                        <div class="translations">explain</div>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
```

I'm trying to get "explain" to text variable in python.

Comment: Hi. It is good practice to search before asking, how about this thread, might be helpfull... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899069/using-selenium-in-python-select-html-page-element-content-with-xpath :))

Comment: I already tried doing what I found before. I am probably making some stupid mistake in my code and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
div.caption div#question_speaker+div
```

**XPATH:**

```
//div[@class='caption']//div[@id='question_speaker']//following-sibling::div
```

Before using them make sure that they are unique in **HTML-DOM**

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code:**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='caption']//div[@id='question_speaker']//following-sibling::div"))).text)
```

You'll need below import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```