# Having problem getting text with Selenium WebDriver in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get text from [this site](http://www.lutanho.net/play/hex.html) using Selenium WebDriver and here is my code.

```
from os import system
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.lutanho.net/play/hex.html")

msgbox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div > form > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(9) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > input")
msg = msgbox.text

print(msg)
```

I want to get the message in the selected box.
I expect the value of `msg` would become something likes " Red to move." or " Blue has won !".
However, the result of `msg` is empty, indicating that `msg` did not get any value from `msg = msgbox.text`.

I wonder why `msg` does not change every time when I execute a move?

By the way, I have check [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python), but it did not help in my case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that, since the text is in an input and not a normal element you need to get the text by calling `msg = msgbox.get_attribute('value')` because that's where the text is stored in the html.

PS: To have it updating you need to re-set the msg variable to `msgbox.get_attribute('value')` after you make a move, each time you make a move.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is return that value by executing:

```
msg = driver.execute_script("return window.document.OptionsForm.Msg.value")
```