# Shorten expression for Python exceptions handling

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, exception, contextmanager

I'm using `try`/`except` to check for `xpath` alternative sources for input into variables from a website.

It will have to do this many times, so I'm looking for a way to shorten the expression. Perhaps a context manager can be used somehow?

In this example, I am checking for two alternative xpath sources for the variables `issuer` and `name`.

```
try:
    xpath_issuer = ".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"
    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
try:
    xpath_issuer = ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"
    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
try:
    xpath_name = ".//*[@id='cols']/div[1]/div[1]/h1"
    find_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_name)
    name = re.search(r"(.+)", find_name.text).group()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Comment: Define a function that takes an XPath expression and contains the try/except code, as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150013/423105. Have it return None when a NoSuchElementException occurs. Call the function three times, with three different XPath expressions... but stopping if the function returns a result other than None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
listXPath = [".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]", ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a", ".//*[@id='cols']/div[1]/div[1]/h1"]
class Work():
    def __init__(self):
        self.getIssuer()

    def getIssuer(self):
        for i in range(len(listXPath)):
            xPath = listXPath[i]
            try:
                find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
                issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
            except:
                pass

# Run clas
Work()
```

You seems to have 3 different options for `xpath_issuer` so you loop through all of those. then you set `find_issuer`. After that you do something with `issuer`.

Maybe you can try to let `issuer` return something that will indicate if something is found. If you pass `issuer` apparently it worked, then do a return statement.

For example:

```
listXPath = [".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]", ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a", ".//*[@id='cols']/div[1]/div[1]/h1"]
class Work():
    def __init__(self):
        x = self.getIssuer()
        print(x)

    def getIssuer(self):
        for i in range(len(listXPath)):
            xPath = listXPath[i]
            try:
                find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
                issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
                return 'DoneIt'
            except:
                pass

# Run clas
Work()
```

Comment: I see the 3rd one in your example is something else the `issuer`. I think my example will still give you an idea. You could also make 2 different definitions then. One for `issuer`, and one for `name`.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get `NameError: global name 'issuer' is not defined`. Any idea why? This happens when it tries to pass on `issuer` out of the loop. As long as it's in the loop, it can find `issuer`.

Comment: It seems like it successfully runs `try`, but then it also always runs `except` also, and that negates everything so nothing is passed on in `issuer`. Could that be right?

Comment: I don't realy have an understanding what `issuer` would be supposed to do?

Comment: `issuer` is the variable that I want to write to a csv later. It is extracted with `re.search` from `find_issuer`, which in turn comes from the xpath.