# Python, Selenium: How to check existence of an element?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to go through a website one page at a time, clicking on the element `next`, which in the HTML code is `class="pg-next"`. Eventually, though, I'm going to get to the end, and there won't be a  `next` element anymore, at which point I'd like to stop the loop. I have something like this:

```
pg_next_exists = True
while pg_next_exists:
    #
    # carry out necessary actions
    #
    if ...: # if the pg-next element can be found
        pass
    else:
        pg_next_exists = False # at which point the while loop stops
```

How do I check if that element still exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Selenium WebDriver - Checking element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/python-selenium-webdriver-checking-element-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `wait` try something like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://example.com/')

try:
     wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10) 
     search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'next')))
     search.click()
except:
     # Process element not found here
```

Comment: what's the point of creating a variable `search`? you don't do anything with it