# Scraping - How to find tag of a webelement using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

For instance if i have a webelement and i want to check if it contains h2 tag or not.. is it possible? if yes then how

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ajite\Desktop\web scraping\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('....')

header = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/h2')

if header.contains('h2'):
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccesful")
```

header variable contains h2 tag but i cannot use header.contains since its a webelement and not a text

> Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    if header.contains('h2'):
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/9567069/8944057.

Comment: Can you sumup your Manual Step along with the relevant HTML please?

Comment: I have updated my answer , have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tag_name` method to get the tag name of the webelement like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in")
print ("Launching chrome")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Search"]')
print("element.tag_name "+element.tag_name)
if element.tag_name == "input":
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccesful")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: @RatmirAsanov , its not about python or java , its about selenium. if selenium provide some method for java means it obviously provide in python too. I have updated and verified my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the *webelement* contains ` tag or not you can use the following code block :

```
header = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/h2')
if 'h2' in header.tag_name:
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccesful")
```