# How to pair an element's children by CSS selector using Selenium WebDriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to scrape information from many web-pages. I wonder if it's possible to select multiple children elements by CSS selector. The HTML structure looks like:

```html
<section id="education">
  <div class="degree">
    <h3 class="school"> School1 </h3>
    <p class="year"> 2002-2008 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="degree">
    <h3 class="school"> School2 </h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

In this case, I want to select the school names with their corresponding year ranges. But if I simply use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('section[id="education"] div[class="school"]')
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('section[id="education"] p[class="year"]')
```

I will get two lists: `[School1, School2]` and `['2002-2008']`, and I won't be able to tell which school corresponds to year range `'2002-2008'`. So, is it possible to combine the corresponding school name and year range together? If there are other ways to get around it, it would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through `.degree` tags and extract the required information from it in pairs. Here's how to do it the normal way:

```
education = driver.find_element_by_id("education")
for degree in education.find_element_by_class_name("degree"):
    school = degree.find_element_by_class_name("school")
    year = degree.find_element_by_class_name("year")
    print(school.text, year.text)
```

And here's how to do it using CSS selector:

```
for degree in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#education .degree"):
    school = degree.find_element_by_css_selector(".school")
    year = degree.find_element_by_css_selector(".year")
    print(school.text, year.text)
```

---

Note: as @Andersson commented, you should check if elements (`.year` and `.school`) exist if it's possible to be missing using one of the methods mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069). Otherwise, this code might throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Note that for second `.degree` there is no `p.year` node, so your `year = degree.find_element_by_class_name("year")` will return `NoSuchElementException`. You might need to implement `try`/`except` block

Comment: @Andersson true, I'll add a note