# Trying to find the element in a website using selenium but if else condition is not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find some elements in a website, if find I have to print **check_1** or **check_2** or if not, print **none**. But I am stuck at if else condition as if-else condition is not working. 
my code:

```
try:
    if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hero__media'):
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'grid'
        print('grid')

    elif driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexigrid--no-sublinks.flexigrid--4-2up'):
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'banner'
        print('banner')
    else:
        raise Exception('This is the exception you expect to handle')
except Exception as error:
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'none'
    print('none')
```

Last else is throwing manual exception so if I can't find the element it will go to except.
Edit 1: I tried and changed the condition from if to if else now again the 2nd condition is not working, something is wrong with if else.
Edit1_Code:

````
    if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flexigrid--no-sublinks.flexigrid--4-2up'):
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'grid'
        print('grid')
    elif driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.hero__media'):
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'banner'
        print('banner')
    else:
        raise Exception('This is the exception you expect to handle')
except Exception as error:
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'none'
    print('none')```
````

Comment: can you change `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` to `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` in `elif` condition and try

Comment: @NarendraR tried still not working. It is not taking if else condition

Comment: You mean your are checking whether checkbox present on webpage ?

Comment: `button =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hero__media')
//To check button is present on page
if (len(button)>0):`

Comment: The issue here is my if else is not working, So whatever I put in if else, it is not working. I switched if condition with if else condition and if else condition was working

Answer (score 0):

Try length count and check if it works.

````
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.hero__media'))>0:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'grid'
            print('grid')

        elif len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexigrid--no-sublinks.flexigrid--4-2up'))>0:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'banner'
            print('banner')
        else:
            raise Exception('This is the exception you expect to handle')


    except Exception as error:
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = 'none'
        print('none')```
last else is throwing manual exception so if I can't find the element it will go to except.
````

Comment: Still not working I don't know why but it is not going to if else condition after failing at if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_elements`, get size and check if it not 0:

```
value = 'none'
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.hero__media')) > 0:
    value = 'grid'

elif len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexigrid--no-sublinks.flexigrid--4-2up')) > 0:
    value = 'banner'

print(value)
sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = value
```

Problem in your code is if first element not exist Selenium throw `NoSuchElementException` and skip other code. Fall to `except` part and never go to `elif`.

You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/python-selenium-webdriver-checking-element-exists/36166132) how to check if element exist.

Comment: Why should I check the length? I just want to know if the element (of 'CSS selector') is present on a website or not

Comment: Checking length of find elements give you how many elements exist in the DOM, 0 means not exist.