# How to check if an element exists in the DOM?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know there is CSS in web by using selenium python

this is my code

```
for i in range(10000):
    time.sleep(1)

    date_css = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("time.FH9sR.Nzb55")

    if not date_css:
        date_css = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("time._1o9PC Nzb55")

    date = date_css.text # 날짜 선택
    datetime = date_css.get_attribute("datetime")
    like_css = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5")

    if like_css:
        if like_css.text == "좋아요":
            like_number = 0
        else:
            like_number = int(like_css.text[4:-1])
    else:
        like_number = 0
```

end this is error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5"}
```

So i want to know there is `button.sqdOp.yWX7d._8A5w5` in the web.

Answer (score 0):

already answered here: [Checking if element exists with Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/checking-if-element-exists-with-python-selenium)

I suggest looking at "Brian says Reinstate Monica"s answer