# Using Selenium to grab contents of lines in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium to grab the line of a text file, input that line into an element, click the submit option, and continue to do every line in the txt file until it is done. What I have tried is only pasting in the entire text file which is not what I want. The element I will be sending the keys to is below.

`newalias = driver.find_element_by_id('mailbox_alias_source')`

I hope this makes sense and you guys can help, Thanks!

Comment: Use newalias.send_keys(lineoftext) after that. What part did you need help with?

Comment: i needed help with grabbing the first line of text in the txt file, then having it type it in to the element, then I want it to automatically continue that process for every line of the text file until it completes.

Comment: Does the page reload at all? After the submit.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet. I'm still trying to read the contents of the text file and have it type in each line, and click the submit button 1 by 1. When I manually type something in and click submit, yes the page refreshes.

Comment: You might need some waits after the submits to get the element again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be a start.

```
file = open ("data.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    newalias = driver.find_element_by_id('mailbox_alias_source')
    newalias.send_keys(line.strip())  
file.close()
```

Comment: this actually seems to be going in the right direction. When I click the create button, there are 2 elements that have a chance of coming up and depending on which one it is decides what I need the script to do next. How can I make an if statement that includes both elements and will do something different for both? thank you for helping, I'm new to python, just trying to learn a little. Have a good day.

Comment: I am trying to get it to clear the textbox if it is wrong, and I can't get it to work. I have tried this:

Comment: it looks weird when I paste it in here so I put it in a pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/ASvJUQKA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/checking-if-element-exists-with-python-selenium look at this for checking if element exists.

Comment: here is the error I get:

https://pastebin.com/Wz2QJ3RR

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome for that error,

Comment: Ok, I got a lot working. I am now trying to make it so when this element exists, it sends a message of the data that worked, to a discord webhook. An example would be if it tries "goodemail" and it works, the element exists, and i want it to send to the webhook "goodemail is successful" if that makes sense. How would I do this? I believe the checking if an element exist is working, I am using css for that. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Might want to add another question with all your code and vote this answer.

Comment: ok I made it, thanks again for helping. Means a lot.