# How to check id an element is present within another webelement like a <div> in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to see if a div with a particular class name has an image inside it. I am using.

```
picUrl=[]
        eachDiv =self.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='NiLAwe y6IFtc R7GTQ keNKEd j7vNaf nID9nc']")
        for index, individualDiv in enumerate(eachDiv):
           
            if(individualDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[@class='tvs3Id QwxBBf']").get_attribute('src')):
                picUrl.append(individualDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[@class='tvs3Id QwxBBf']").get_attribute('src'))
                print('present')
            else:
                picUrl.append(" no pic ")
                print('not')
        return picUrl
```

but the condition never reaches inside the else condition even if the div doesn't have a  tag with that class name.

Answer (score 0):

it'll depend on what the result of that expression inside your if-statement is:

```
if(individualDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[@class='tvs3IdQwxBBf']").get_attribute('src')):
```

in python for example `if([])` is False but `if([[]])` is True... I guess you need to make that expression a little more explicit. You could try something like

```
if len(individualDiv.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//img[@class='tvs3IdQwxBBf']")) > 0:
```

Or you could use find_by_xpath with a `try` `except` block as statet [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150013/7408462), which is quite elegant.