# How do I check that an element does not exist, using Python and Appium?

Tags: python, cucumber, appium, appium-android, python-appium

Please see a snippet of what I am working with.

Below is my step definition file, `home_step.py`

```
@Then('the screen is verified')
def step_impl(context):
   context.app.home_page.check_element_nonexistent('Some Tab')
```

Below is my page objects file, `home_page.py`

```
#Element's accessibility-id is defined here
def __init__(self, driver):
   super().__init__(driver)
   self.driver = driver
   self.some_tab = 'some-id'

#I call find_element() here
def el_some_tab(self):
   return self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, self.some_tab)

#Attempt to check for nonexistent elements
def check_element_nonexistent(self, element)
   try:
      if element == 'Some Tab':
         assert self.el_some_tab().is_displayed()
   except NoSuchElementException:
      return False
   return True
```

My attempt to check for the nonexistent item came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/checking-if-an-element-exists-with-python-selenium#:%7E:text=check_exists_by_xpath).

The above snippet runs successfully, it should not since the element, `some-tab` was nonexistent during the run.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def is_displayed(self, locator: Locator) -> bool:
        is_displayed: bool = False
        count = len(self.driver.find_elements(*locator))
        if count > 0:
            is_displayed = True
        return is_displayed
```

OR

```
    # try:
    #     is_displayed = self.driver.find_element(*locator).is_displayed()
    # except NoSuchElementException:
    #     l.info(f'{locator} is displayed: {is_displayed}')
```