# web scraping button Next condition python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can i make the condition it does not go through this code if there is the next button because there are page does not contain the next button

I would like a condition for the next button to check if it exists or not how I can do it

```py
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurants-g23084688-Beardsley_New_Brunswick.html"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
with open("details.txt","w") as filenam:
  if hasattr(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk"]').text,"Next"):
   while True:
   try :
    container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='Lwqic Cj b']")
    for j in range(len(container)):
           li=container[j].get_attribute("href")
           links1.append(li)
           print(li)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/a[@class="nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk"]'))).click()
   except:
           break
# else:
          container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='Lwqic Cj b']")
          for j in range(len(container)):
           li=container[j].get_attribute("href")
           links1.append(li)
           print(li)
       
  for l in links1:
        filenam.writelines(l+"\n")
```

Comment: Seem like this question might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/checking-if-an-element-exists-with-python-selenium

Comment: Update the question with your code trials for a page having _**next**_ button.